# Hibernate criteria join

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two class such as:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String refId;
}


@Entity
public class Account{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String accountNr;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String accountType;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String refId;
}
```

I want to join this two classes on refId for ordering on a field of Account such as:

```
select c.* from Customer as c inner join Account as a on a.refId=c.refId orderBy a.accountType
```

Is there any way to do such query in criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't normally allow you to do an "at-demand" join via `Criteria` as in your SQL query. [However, this appears to indeed be possible using a work-around of having multiple Criterias.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2102080/988713)

But if you follow Alex's suggestion to map an association in your `Entity` classes, you can create a much simpler `Criteria` like this, as `Customer` would have an `account` object already "mapped" to it:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class)
        .createCriteria("account")
        .addOrder(Order.asc("accountType"));
```

To do the associations, in your `Entity` classes you could replace the `refId` field with the relating object. So, in the `Customer` class, you could have an `Account` object association, like so (and vice versa):

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    // Instead of "refId" field:
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Account account;
}

@Entity
public class Account {
    // Instead of "refId" field:
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "refIdColName")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Assuming this was a one-to-one relationship. [You don't need to reference the primary key in one-to-one mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670741/orm-onetoone-mapping-on-non-primary-key-join-column-book-and-inventory-mapped).

Comment: given link (DetachedCriteria) worked as expected, refId is what is desired, I have no option but proceed that way. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should use relationships between tables e.g. `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`.
After that it will be easy to write `HQL`.
You can read more about it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional).

Comment: but in my case classes are not reffering to each other it is a oneToOne relation but not on primary keys